# What's the problem in the next sequence of Java/SQL code?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I made an update to a table in access via Java code, and it doesn't work. But, when I print to the console the result of executeUpdate(), it shows me 1, but in the database, no change. Can you tell me where's the problem, please?

```
System.out.println("here");
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE StocProduseCuFactura SET cantitate = " +
    "cantitate - ? WHERE nume = ? and um = 'buc'");
st.setInt(1, cant);
st.setString(2, p.getNume());
System.out.println(st.executeUpdate());
st.close();
```

I forgot to say, if i run that SQL code in access, it's working.

Comment: are values of `cant` and `p.getNume()` correct? Also you have `= cantitate - ?`. Is that minus intentional ?

Comment: Are you using transactions manually? Do you commit the transaction properly?

Comment: yes, they are correct. cantitate - ? is the quantity from the database minus quantity to be decreased from it

Comment: before that code, I just simply get the connection, via drivermanager, and after that, i'm closing it. It's working in other cases, like insert, select, delete, but in this case - UPDATE - it prints the number of updates done, but there is no difference in the database, when i check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ensured the transaction is commited?

Comment: I don't use Transaction, I use just a Connection and a PreparedStatement, with executeUpdate(). But in other cases it's working, and in this case too, it shows me the number of updates done, but in the database, no difference.

Comment: Trying calling the commit() method on the Connection object after you close the statement.

So instead of just st.close() do:

st.close();
conn.commit();

Answer (score 1):

people, sorry for bothering you, but I realized it was my stupid mistake. There is another method after this sequence of code, that made that table right as it was before the update, that why I didn't see any changes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As others have told, transaction is the area you might need to focus upon. Try setting the autoCommit to true and false explicitly and try the update query.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Moreover, check for locks on the database. Some other connection might have acquired a lock and waiting for it to be committed, but then in that case, your update query would have not gotten fired at all. But just try restarting the database.

Answer (score 0):

Johnny Keys is probably on the right trail.  Most likely your connection isn't set to commit the transaction automatically, so when you close it the transaction is rolled back and your change is removed.

You might try putting

```
conn.setAutocommit(true);
```

at the top to see if it makes a difference.  The other possibility is "cant" is always zero.  In that case you will be setting cantitate = cantitate (i.e. no change), but update will still report every row the "where" clause was satisfied.